# Don't have access to template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Why can't I do this:

```
template<template<class E>class Derived>
struct X
{
    static void f()
    {
        Derived<E>::value;
    }
};
```

The problem that I have is that I cannot compile this code for the reason that I'm getting an error saying that param E hasn't been declared.  Is there a way that I can use this formal param or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters of template template parameters don't get arguments, and therefore don't usually have names. Partial specialization is the exception to this rule. Try this instead:

```
template<class> // Derived<E> is only only parameter
struct X; // but you actually need two parameters, Derived and E

template< template <class> class Derived, class E >
struct X< Derived< E > > // so use partial specialization.
{
    static void f()
    {
        Derived<E>::value; // only reason to want this is to
        Derived<int>::value; // use different specializations
    }
};
```

Of course, if you don't need to re-specialize on `Derived< something_else >`, just ignore the fact that `Derived<E>` is a template specialization:

```
template<class Derived>
struct X
{
    static void f()
    {
        Derived::value;
    }
};

X< my_class< something > > my_x; // a specialized class template is a class
```

Answer (score 2):

Your template parameter `Derived` is a template itself, `E` is its formal parameter.
You need to pass a value for it, too.

Maybe you need the following:

```
template<template<class E>class Derived, class T>
struct X
{
    static void f()
    {
        Derived<T>::value;
    }
};
```

Comment: @Potatoswatter: indeed, one can just write `template<template<class>class Derived>`, because the formal parameter is not going to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that parameter because it is just there to mean that `Derived` is a template with exactly one type argument.

You'd call `f` like this:

```
template <class T>
struct ZZZ {};

X<ZZZ>::f();
  ^^^
```

Note that there is no `E` in this instantiation.

Unless there is a reason to use template templates, you could just use a regular template, else you'll need to pass `E` as a separate argument, making the call look like this:

```
X<ZZZ, int>::f();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have your syntax a bit muddled.

```
template<class E>
struct X
{
    static void f()
    {
        Derived<E>::value;
    }
}
```

should work fine.